# lvconvert --merge not completing

Tags: lvm, snapshot

I have a root LVM "lvroot" and a snapshot of that root LVM "rootsnap". I broke something in lvroot when performing an initramfs update and can't boot into it, so I booted from the rootsnap snapshot available in the grub menu and attempted to revert to the snapshot using the lvconvert --merge command. Upon reboot I still cannot boot into lvroot, so am booted into rootsnap and the merge has not completed. I think this may be because the system needs to boot into the original lvroot to complete the merge/revert process. Something is broken in lvroot that will not allow it to boot.

Am I correct that the merge is incomplete because the system is not booting into the original lvroot? If yes, is my only recourse to repair lvroot and make it bootable? Or is there another path for me to take to get this merge completed?